# Use Jensen's Inequality to prove $\sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{C} \leq \dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> Prove that for any triangle $ABC$, have $\sin{A}+\sin{B}+\sin{C} \leq \dfrac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

I know that we have to use Jensen's inequality here, but I am not sure how to apply it. We know that $A+B+C = 180^{\circ}$, so seeing that sine is concave on $[0,\pi]$, we can let $f(x) = \sin{x}$.

Comment: $\frac{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{3}\le \sin\left(\frac{A+B+C}{3}\right)=\sin 60^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

For a concave function, such as sine on $[0,\pi]$, we have
$$\sin\Bigl(\frac{A+B+C}3\Bigr)=\sin\frac\pi3\le\frac13(\sin A+\sin B+\sin C),$$
whence the required inequality.